# Remove certain character of string PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need to remove the third character of a string. Here's what I tried.

```
$my_string['2'] = "";
```

This worked find, but when I tried to put this variable in a MySQL query, it returned errors.

What is the best way to remove a certain character (character 3 in my case) from a string?

Comment: what query? what errors ? - crystal ball in the shop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try out [substr_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php).

For example:

```
$new_string = substr_replace($my_string, '', 2, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an integer as index, not a string:

```
$my_string[2] = '';
```

Comment: This will thrown a warning: Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset